# Sed to remove user specified block

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have a long .XML file (60K or so lines) that I'm working with. I need bash to start the script and have a user input a name to be removed from the .XML file. I was thinking `sed` but if there is a better option, I'm open to that too. Here is what I've got so far:

```
echo -n "Type media to remove and press [ENTER]"
read TARGET

while true; do
    read -p "Are you sure you wish to remove $TARGET from the system?" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) SED COMMAND HERE; break;;
        [Nn]* ) echo "Cancelling..."; exit;;
    * ) echo "---please answer [Y] or [N]";;
    esac
done
```

And here is a section of the .XML file. Note that this section I'm posting repeats through the .XML hundreds of times. The only difference in the blocks are what I have labelled "**corrupt**" for this example.

```
<media>
  <name>"corrupt"</name>
  <parent>system</parent>
  <location>/path/to/the/"corrupt".zip</location>
  <video>/another/path/"corrupt".flv</video>
  <images>
    <image>
      <type>saved</type>
      <image-file>/yet/another/path/"corrupt".png</image-file>
    </image>
  </images>
</media>
```

In this example, I would wish to remove "**corrupt**" from the .XML file. I think it is important to say that there is only 1 instance of "**corrupt**" in the .XML file. Also, for other "**corrupt_files**", there are no spaces in the file names, only underscores or dashs.

So `sed` would need to remove the entire xml block containing "**corrupt**" information, leaving no empty lines where it removed text, then the script would overwrite the current "media.xml" file.

I hope this question isn't confusing.

Comment: `sed` is really the [wrong tool for any kind of structured input such as XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)...

Comment: You write 'So sed would need to remove the entire xml block containing "corrupt" information'; what do you mean by "the entire xml block"? Do you mean just the `<location>...</location>` and `<video>...</video>` elements, or do you mean the entire `<media>...</media>` element? As @Jubobs points out, either way, `sed` is probably the wrong tool for the job, but which one you are referring to will affect the answer.

Comment: @Brian ...I'm sorry. By block, I mean the entire example of xml I posted. That is what I am referring to as a block. So everything in and including <media>... </media>

Comment: @jubobs I don't have to use `sed` , that's just what I thought would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use correct `xml` tool, but this  `gnu awk` removes the block where  `name` contains `corrupt`

```
cat file
<media>
  <name>"test1"</name>
  <parent>system</parent>
  <location>/path/to/the/"test1".zip</location>
  <video>/another/path/"test1".flv</video>
  <images>
    <image>
      <type>saved</type>
      <image-file>/yet/another/path/"test1".png</image-file>
    </image>
  </images>
</media>
<media>
  <name>"corrupt"</name>
  <parent>system</parent>
  <location>/path/to/the/"corrupt".zip</location>
  <video>/another/path/"corrupt".flv</video>
  <images>
    <image>
      <type>saved</type>
      <image-file>/yet/another/path/"corrupt".png</image-file>
    </image>
  </images>
</media>
<media>
  <name>"test2"</name>
  <parent>system</parent>
  <location>/path/to/the/"test2".zip</location>
  <video>/another/path/"test2".flv</video>
  <images>
    <image>
      <type>saved</type>
      <image-file>/yet/another/path/"test2".png</image-file>
    </image>
  </images>
</media>
```

```
awk -v RS="<media>" '!/<name>"corrupt/ && NR>1 {print RS$0}'
<media>
  <name>"test1"</name>
  <parent>system</parent>
  <location>/path/to/the/"test1".zip</location>
  <video>/another/path/"test1".flv</video>
  <images>
    <image>
      <type>saved</type>
      <image-file>/yet/another/path/"test1".png</image-file>
    </image>
  </images>
</media>

<media>
  <name>"test2"</name>
  <parent>system</parent>
  <location>/path/to/the/"test2".zip</location>
  <video>/another/path/"test2".flv</video>
  <images>
    <image>
      <type>saved</type>
      <image-file>/yet/another/path/"test2".png</image-file>
    </image>
  </images>
</media>
```

Comment: seems whenever I `cd` to file and run `awk -v RS="<media>" '!/<name>"corrupt/ && NR>1 {print RS$0}'` nothing happens. The actions starts, but I have to `ctrl+c` to get it to exit and the .xml file to be changed is the same as before. Maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: haha...geesh. But still, `cat test.xml > awk -v RS="<media>" '!/<name>"corrupt/ && NR>1 {print RS$0}' test.xml > test-new.xml` just seems to add a blank space between every block.

Comment: AH! Just had to remove the symbol " that is in `'!/<name>"corrupt/` That seems to remove the corrupt block just fine and adds a blank space between the blocks, but I can just another command to remove the blank lines.

Comment: @GHO5TLIKE5WAYZE One negative thing with setting `RS` like this is the blank line.  You can remove it later with  `sed` or  `awk` .  But a good rule is not to use  `cat` with  `sed/awk` or other programs that can read data itself. `awk -v RS="<media>" '!/<name>"corrupt/ && NR>1 {print RS$0}' test.xml > test-new.xml` is a good way to do it.

Comment: But now a new issue....there are tags that fall above and below the blocks like so
`<file>
  <media-list>
    {xml blocks}
  </media-list>
</file>`

Seems that the command strips all of these tags out along with the "corrupt" block. Leaving me only the `<media>` blocks. I suppose I could just `sed` them back into the file before overwriting the original.

Comment: It is because the <media> tag that `awk` searches for appears above the blocks in the `<media-list>` tag. I suppose it still sees the word "media" in there and removes it. No worries...will just `sed` them back into place.

Comment: @GHO5TLIKE5WAYZE If you post more of you code, so I can see what goes wrong, I may be able to help you.  You may possible narrow down the  `RS` to not hit extra data.'

Comment: too much to post in the comments. Email perhaps? Then we could post the solution here and mark it answered.